# How to listen to FM radio in 1607?

Tags: lumia, radio, redstone-builds

In build 10586 and earlier, there was a separate FM radio app. After the forced update to 14393, it disappeared. How can i listen to radio now from my Lumia 640?

Answer (score 1):

The official FM Radio app [has been discontinued](http://mspoweruser.com/microsoft-removing-fm-radio-app-windows-10-mobile) by Microsoft.

If you want to keep listening to FM radio, you can use a third-party app. [This article](http://winsupersite.com/windows-phone/alternative-fm-radio-apps-windows-10-mobile) has several suggestions - [Radio FM Phone](https://www.microsoft.com/store/apps/9wzdncrfhxns), [FM Radio Player](https://www.microsoft.com/store/apps/9wzdncrdlxnm) and [Tunable FM Radio](https://www.microsoft.com/store/apps/9wzdncrfjc3r).

Alternatively, you could try an Internet-based radio app, like [iHeartRadio](https://www.microsoft.com/store/apps/9wzdncrfj223), [Pandora](https://www.microsoft.com/store/apps/9wzdncrfj46v) or [TuneIn Radio](https://www.microsoft.com/store/apps/9wzdncrfj3sf).

Comment: If this is indeed true, then this is… idiotic. Why remove an app that practically doesn’t need maintenance. If third-party apps still work as before, then this is not Android where random devices stopped working with every major OS upgrade due to driver bugs

Comment: For internet radio, i actually use this app: [RADYO](https://www.microsoft.com/pl-pl/store/p/radyo/9wzdncrfjb0m) It is lightweight, supports pinning of stations and doesn’t ask unnecessary permissions